# Seperate array into three new arrays using inequalities in Python

Tags: python, arrays, inequality

I am trying to split an array into three new arrays using inequalities.

This will give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
measurement = [1, 5, 10, 13, 40, 43, 60]

for x in measurement:
    if 0 < x < 6:
        small = measurement
    elif 6 < x < 15:
        medium = measurement
    else
        large = measurement
```

Intended Output:

```
small = [1, 5]
medium = [10, 13]
large = [40, 43, 60]
```

Comment: In your code, `measurement` is the whole original list so you are assigning the whole list to `small`, `medium`, `large`. You should be adding the element that you are comparing (`x`) to these lists. Please check the [Python documentation about lists](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures) and specifically `list.append()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
arr = np.array(measurement)     
small = arr[(arr>0)&(arr<6)]    # array([1, 5])
medium = arr[(arr>6)&(arr<15)]  # array([10, 13])
large = arr[(arr>15)]           # array([40, 43, 60])
```

You can also use dictionary:

```
d = {'small':[], 'medium':[], 'large':[]}
for x in measurement:
    if 0 < x < 6:
        d['small'].append(x)
    elif 6 < x < 15:
        d['medium'].append(x)
    else:
        d['large'].append(x)
```

Output:

```
{'small': [1, 5], 'medium': [10, 13], 'large': [40, 43, 60]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array is sorted, you can do :

```
measurement = [1, 5, 10, 13, 40, 43, 60]
one_third = len(measurement) // 3
two_third = (2 * len(measurement)) // 3

small = measurement[:one_third]
medium = measurement[one_third : two_thirds]
large = measurement[two_thirds:]
```

You could easily generalize to any number of split with a loop. Not sure if you wanted explicitly those inequalities or just split with the array in three. If its the first one, my answer is not right

Answer (score 0):

With the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) you can do something along these lines:

```
from bisect import bisect
breaks=[0,6,15,float('inf')]
buckets={}

m = [1, 5, 10, 13, 40, 43, 60]

for e in m:
    buckets.setdefault(breaks[bisect(breaks, e)], []).append(e)
```

You then have a dict of lists matching what you are looking for:

```
>>> buckets
{6: [1, 5], 15: [10, 13], inf: [40, 43, 60]}
```

You can also form tuples of your break points and list that will become a dict to form the sub lists:

```
m = [1, 5, 10, 13, 40, 43, 60]
buckets=[('small',[]), ('medium',[]), ('large',[]), ('other',[])]

breaks=[(0,6),(6,15),(15,float('inf'))]

for x in m:
    buckets[
        next((i for i,t in enumerate(breaks) if t[0]<=x<t[1]), -1)
           ][1].append(x)

>>> dict(buckets)
{'small': [1, 5], 'medium': [10, 13], 'large': [40, 43, 60], 'other': []}
```